# Jackson JSON ObjectMapper.readvalue

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm going through code examples on converting the Java object to a JSON and I came across this:

```
HashMap<String, Object> filters = new ObjectMapper().readValue(filterStr, HashMap.class);
```

where

```
String filterStr;
```

sorry, but what exactly is the above line of code doing? I went through other example [here.](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/) I can see that readValue() has been overridden but how can a string be converted to a HashMap? Shouldn't it be a JSON object and not a string? Thanks.

Comment: This will add all jason attributes to hashmap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ObjectMapper().readValue()
```

is overloaded to do several types of conversions.

If the filterStr is compatible to be converted to a HashMap this will method will do it.

E.g. `filterStr = "{\"name\":\"Tom\", \"age\":\"25\"}";` will give a map with key-value pairs as {age=25, name=Tom}